# text-decoration:underline with handwritten style?

Tags: javascript, css, underline

Is there a CSS trick or possibly a JavaScript library that would take elements styled with `text-decoration: underline` and provide a handwritten-like underline using some sort of image?

If I was doing that myself I guess I would prepare a couple of images to account for different lengths of underline and then somehow dynamically add relative-positioned elements that would put these images into the DOM. But isn't there a better way or even better yet, a ready-to-use solution?

Comment: You can do it with images or possibly with custom fonts, but it wouldn't involve `text-decoration`

Comment: @Borek I'd prefer doing it withouth images and using custom fonts instead but my workflow would have been pretty much the same!

Comment: Can you add some example markup for what you are looking to style?

Comment: Which example would match the method your HTML is currently underlining text?: http://cssdesk.com/93K3v

Comment: https://sharkcoder.com/visual/underline looks pretty awesome.

Comment: Also worth exploring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148460/how-can-i-make-a-curved-text-underline and https://ishadeed.com/article/custom-underline-svg/ https://github.com/shadeed/underliner

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use an image as your element border

For instance I have a markup like this

```
<div class="main">
<h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sat</h2>
  <p> Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Then I can apply the style for h2 to get the underline border as hand-writing style using an image.

```
.main h2 {
  background-image: url(images/underline.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

And the image is 
[image]

Comment: I would need it to be clever, i.e. use different images based on how long the underline should be. Your example is a good start but not a complete solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use border bottom on your element and change the border to be an image?

Comment: Do you mean `border-image`? That's only supported in IE11+.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link: http://alistapart.com/article/customunderlines

It looks like they're just using an image, which they repeat several times or adjust based on the length of the word.  I know you'd rather not use images, but this looks like the best way to get a handwritten effect.