# How can i make a curved text underline?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use CSS and HTML to create a text underline that's curved. The curve in particular has been referred to as a "swoosh" in the design brief I was given, it needs to fall short of the first and last letter (i.e. to underline "help you", it would start at "e" and end at "o" - this part I figure is easy, applying the style to a span tag without the first and last letter), and has to have rounded ends. The swoosh is also not even.

Here's an example: [image]

I'm not super crash hot with CSS, but I know I'm constrained to CSS and HTML in this case - no HTML5 or using javascript to get it done.

So far, I've only managed to come up with this:

```
    .swoosh1 {
      width: 500px; 
      height: 100px;  
      border: solid 5px #cb1829;
      border-color: #cb1829 transparent transparent transparent;
      border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
    }
```

Which looks like this (don't worry about the font): :( [image]

Does anyone have any pointers? Done it before?

Comment: you can also use an svg instead of the text and the underline, because the css that you might write can have browser restriction and compatibility issues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `:after` pseudo-element to hold your underline:

```css
.underlined {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.underlined:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 2px #cb1829;
  border-color: #cb1829 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.small {
  font-size: 60%;
}
.big {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<span class="underlined">Test</span>
<span class="underlined small">Test</span>
<span class="underlined big">Test</span>
```

Comment: Add `clip-path: inset(0 0 50% 0);` to `.underlined:after` to fix Safari issue.

Comment: Great snippet. I've added transform: rotate(-4deg); in order to give it a slight more handwritten design.

Answer (score 3):

Use `:after` and then use `border` and `radius` and `position` it

Learn about pseudo:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

```css
.text:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 15px;
    width: 70px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 37px;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.text{
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Your local</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a read - I'm starting to realise, I've neglected learning about a huge area of knowledge (CSS)!

Comment: The above code did not work as shown within the context.  The line was somewhere up above.  I revised it as follows and I gave you a star up-vote:                                                    /** Begin css code **/                  .text_underline {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    color:red;
}
.text_underline:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 15px;
    width: 95%;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: -25px;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}/** End of css code **/

Comment: In safari it renders as a full ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

make sure to use : **display: inline-block !important;** on underlined class to be responsive.

[image]

Without : **display: inline-block !important;** on underlined class, it will as below on device.

[image]

```css
.underlined {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.underlined::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 0;
    height: 7px;
    width: 100% !important;
    border: solid 8px yellow;
    border-color: yellow transparent transparent transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.big {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="big "> You're connected. Now, <span class="underlined "> automate!</span> </h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to create my own, fully CSS-only, text underline as seen on many websites. Most solutions use an image or SVG, and while SVG's can be pretty good in terms of performance, getting the same/similar effect without loading any additional assets is even better in terms of performance!

The solution below uses pure CSS to create an underline on the chosen text and uses the CSS unit 'ex' for its sizing and positioning, meaning that the underline will scale nicely with font size - see the demo below.

[image]

```css
    span.underline {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap; /* 'Fix' for larger phrases...? */
      text-shadow: 0 .05ex .05ex rgba(0,0,0,0.75); /* Optional but adds a bit more pop */
    }
    span.underline:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: 105%;
      height: 0.75ex;
      border-top-width: 0.25ex; /* Width/weight */
      border-top-style: solid; /* Style */
      border-top-color: #b63e6b; /* Colour */
      border-radius: 50%;
      bottom: -0.6ex;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

[Demo by WPMAD](https://codepen.io/wpmad/pen/GRzaRyV)

Answer (score 0):

To create a curved underline, you can use it after the class name by making the border color transparent and giving a border radius of 64%. Here is the CSS,  you can use your HTML line where you want to underline in the text, just use the down class name and it's done:

```css
.down {
  position: relative;
}

.down:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 2px #6490e2;
  border-color: #f4a804 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 64%;
}
```

```html
<p>hey guyz <strong class="down">welcome</strong></p>
```